# "Introduction" of Enterprise E in DS9

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In the DS9 episode "Trials and Tribble-ations" (season 5 episode 6) there is this small piece of dialog:

> **Dulmur:** Be specific, Captain, which Enterprise? There've been five.
>
> **Lucsly:** Six.

Was this supposed to be a teaser for the new Enterprise E? The episode aired on November 4th 1996 while the premiere of "First Contact" was November 18th and the official release November 22nd. I would have placed such a teaser a little earlier but it would still fit.

Comment: And of course all the trailers and sneak peeks at the film for months before. Of course it was.

Comment: @cde that's exactly the reason why I would have placed such a thing earlier. At that point it wasn't really news anymore. Imagine the reaction of a Trekkie if this was placed before any information about a new movie (or at least it's content) ;-)

Comment: Note that the new "ongoing" comics show that there was another Federation starship called the Enterprise before the Enterprise-A. It was captained by Robert April.

Comment: @Richard but that's not an additional Enterprise. It's the same ship Kirk commanded in TOS. There acctually is a 7th Enterprise with the NX-01 but afaik no one ever spoke of that one before that show aired.

Comment: @andreStannek - The one in the ongoing comics is a **completely different vessel**; http://scifanatic.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/p2.jpg

Comment: @cde Though the trailers did not feature any shots on the new Enterprise's.

Comment: The NX-01 was not an Enterprise chartered under the United Federation of Planets, though. Much like NASA's shuttle orbiter Enterprise (the aircraft carrier Enterprise, the balloon Enterprise, etc. :).

Comment: Remember that *Enterprise* takes place entirely on the Holodeck; that might have been an entirely fictional ship within the Star Trek universe.

Comment: @Lexible good point. But to my understanding it's the same Starfleet (executive vs. legislative). But we are getting a little off topic here ;-)

Comment: @amcintosh: The Enterprise-E is already visible in the first teaser trailer linked to in [an answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/94114/21137), if only on a display.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In-universe, yes, it's likely that he is referring to the Enterprise E. The Enterprise D was destroyed in 2371, the E was launched in 2372 (on stardate 49827.5) and this episode took place in 2373 (stardate never mentioned in the episode, but "Looking for par'Mach in All the Wrong Places", several episodes earlier that season, mentioned stardate 50061.2).

In fact, it seems like such an obvious reference that the trivia section of [the Memory-Alpha article on this episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Trials_and_Tribble-ations_(episode)#The_Enterprise) states it matter-of-factly without citation:

> This episode also contains the first reference to the new Sovereign-class USS Enterprise-E, as the film Star Trek: First Contact hadn't premiered yet. After Sisko mentions the USS Defiant was in front of the Enterprise, Dulmur tells him to be more specific, as there had been five. Lucsly corrects him and says there had been six. (The NX-01 was never in Federation service, and Star Trek: Enterprise didn't exist as a series until 2001, five years after this episode was released.)

This episode takes place months *before* the Battle of Sector 001 (stardate 50893.5, which matches up with the last few episodes of season 5), which means that the Enterprise likely was still undergoing shakedown or was on one of its very first missions. [Memory Beta lists some books](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701-E)) that take place between the E's launch and *First Contact*.

An interesting aside: the [first teaser for First Contact](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkJQK12BnK0), which came out in the summer of 1996, didn't have any exterior shots of the new Enterprise. All of the shots of the Enterprise are clearly reused footage of the D. And according to Memory Alpha:

> As much of the film had yet to be shot when the advertisements were assembled, footage from Star Trek Generations and episodes from Star Trek: The Next Generation and Star Trek: Deep Space Nine was included. Inter-cut with sequences from the film, the reused footage included snippets of "The Best of Both Worlds" and "Emissary".

[Later trailers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxyZQR2d6yw), however, did include such footage.

Comment: The first teaser trailer uses exterior shots of the Galaxy class (Enterprise-D), but the MSD visible in the bridge scenes already shows the Sovereign class (Enterprise-E).

Comment: Great inquiry on the topic. I should have checked the English Memory Alpha article. Usually I just read the German ones as they are usually equally comprehensive.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the teaser trailer (0:43) shows the USS Voyager (NCC-74656) as part of the fight even though (by the timeline) it had already been in the Delta Quadrant for two years. At 0:58, you can also see Sisko's USS Saratoga NCC-31911 which was lost at Wolf-359. Certainly this is a case of grabbing whatever footage was around.